# Should Content-Type header be set for 404 and 204 responses?

Tags: rest, http

I plan to use a HTTP `HEAD /products/{product_id}` request as a low bandwidth way to determine if a product exists.

If it does, I intend to return `204 No Content`. If it does not, I intend to return `404 Not Found`.

In my HTTP service there is some middleware that adds the `Content-Type: application/json`.

The final response is

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Origin
Date: Wed, 07 Aug 2019 16:50:08 GMT
```

All other resources return JSON responses. Should I remove the `Content-Type` header and does it matter for `204` and `404` type responses?

Comment: A response with no content (e.g. 204) does not need a content-type by definition. If it is provided, it will be ignored.

Comment: Using `HEAD` is a bit of a red herring here. [HEAD is identical to GET, except that no content is returned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25653119/13860). So if you would respond to a GET request with content, then, by spec, you SHOULD also include all the same headers, including `Content-Type`, for your HEAD response--just without content. if you would send no content with a GET request, then no Content-Type is needed for either GET or HEAD requests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Content-Type` header is used by the client to interpret the content. If there is no content (as with a HEAD request in general or as with status code 204 for other requests) there does not need to be a `Content-Type` header since no interpretation of the (zero) content need to be done. But it also does not harm, i.e. it will simply be ignored.

If you send content (which is not allowed with HEAD) with status code 404 then you should also send a `Content-Type` header, if you don't send a content (i.e. `Content-length: 0`) then you don't need to add such a header.