# How to check If file exists in the url before use download.file in R

Tags: r, try-catch, rcurl

I have a problem and I don't know how  to solve it. 
I have a list of url direct to download some files.

For example.

```
x<-list("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/paym/coll/assets/html/dla/ea_MID/ea_csv_200219.csv",
"http://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/quickviewexport.do?SERIES_KEY=120.EXR.M.USD.EUR.SP00.A&type=csv")

name_file<-list("name_1.csv","name_2.csv")
```

In this case the script below works fine, but if one o more urls don't work the tryCatch doesen't return me the message. Somebody, please, could help me and tell me where is my mistake?

```
  for(i in seq_along(x)) {
  x<-as.character(x[i])
  nse.folder = paste0("directory_files/",name_file[i])
  tryCatch({download.file(x, destfile = nse.folder, method='curl')}, error = function(e) "Error: this url doesn't work!")
  Sys.sleep(4)
  }
```

To test the script I cut, for example the url, like this:

```
x<-list("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/paym/coll/assets/html/dla/ea_MID/",
"http://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/quickviewexport.do?")
```

Where  should I improve the code ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `HEAD` request. In R it's available in package `httr`. The return codes can be found on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16699223/8245406) may be useful.

A very simple function could be

```
urlFileExist <- function(url){
  HTTP_STATUS_OK <- 200
  hd <- httr::HEAD(url)
  status <- hd$all_headers[[1]]$status
  list(exists = status == HTTP_STATUS_OK, status = status)
}

lapply(x, urlFileExist)
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$exists
#[1] TRUE
#
#[[1]]$status
#[1] 200
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]]$exists
#[1] TRUE
#
#[[2]]$status
#[1] 200
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Was very helpful, but in the end I used the function try. 
What I did? 
I used this solution: 
try(download.file(x, destfile = nse.folder, method='curl', quite =TRUE))